# Calibration of Covariance Matrix for a Cumulative Period Return

Tags: volatility, equities, portfolio-optimization, modern-portfolio-theory, minimum-variance

I am trying to compute optimized weights (minimum-variance portfolio) for a cumulative return over a period (weekly or fortnightly). In a daily return setting, it is quite simple, I just compute a daily covariance matrix over the past 21 days (yes I used a monthly historical rolling window for the calibration in this case) and optimize the weights based on a minimized volatility/variance goal.

My question is, if I were to change from a daily return to periodic cumulative return setting (be it weekly or fortnightly), do I need to change the frequency of the covariance matrix for optimizing the weights? i.e. calibrating the covariance matrix using historical periodic returns (weekly or fortnightly) OR calibrating the covariance matrix using historical daily returns and 'lengthening' the covariance matrix by multiplying the whole thing element-wise by 5 (weekly) or 10 (fortnightly).

I am attempting a replication of DeMiguel, Plyakha, Uppal, Vilkov (2013): *Improving Portfolio Selection Using Option-Implied Volatility and Skewness*.

Comment: Simply "multiplying" the covariance matrix by some constant factor will not change the resulting optimal weights as the scaling factor will cancel in the MVP equation. You will ned to re-calculate your covariance matrix using weekly (or bi-weekly) non-overlapping returns; same holds for the return.

Comment: Hi @Kermittfrog, thanks for the response. It is a helpful point on how the MVP weights do not change simply because one lengthens the covariance matrix. On using the weekly or bi-weekly returns, the authors used overlapping returns because they did not want the returns to be dependent on the chosen day. For example, the returns chosen on Monday to Friday may be less than the returns from Tuesday to Monday. But back to your point, is there a reason why the covariance matrix should be calculated with weekly returns? Thanks.